# codedom add reference

Tags: c#, reference, codedom, mail-sender

I want make a mail sender generator . but I have problem with codedom reference . my result is :
"The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I cant add system.net.mail because system.net.mail is`nt a dll file.
my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace compilerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void compileIt1()
        {
            //mail sender code
            string source =
            @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace mail_sender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(""smtp.gmail.com"", 587);

            NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(""sendermail@gmail.com"", ""password"");

            smtp.Credentials = myCredentials;

            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
            smtp.Send(""sendermail@gmail.com"", ""tomaill@gmail.com"", ""titel"", ""mail body"");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

}
           ";

            //version
            Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
                };
            //code type
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

            //output file
            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
            {
                OutputAssembly = "D:\\mailsender.EXE",
                GenerateExecutable = true
            };
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Net.Dll");

            //compile
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

            //errors
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Errors: {0}", results.Errors.Count);
            foreach (CompilerError err in results.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR {0}", err.ErrorText);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            compileIt1();
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I have :
.net 3.5
VS 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SmtpClient` et al. are defined in the `System` assembly, not `System.Net`.